# After macOS update, monitor keeps defaulting to variable refresh rate, goes black

Tags: display, sleep-wake, displayport

I've got an Acer K272HUL monitor and an M1 Mac mini running macOS 12.6 Monterey. Before this latest update (forget what I was on before), the monitor worked fine. Now, whenever my Mac sleeps the monitor, it comes up black when I try to wake it. I have other monitors, so I'm able to go into sysprefs. The Acer apparently automatically gets set to a variable refresh rate. If I set it to constant 75Hz, it works again. I don't know if the monitor used variable rate before the macOS update or not.

[image]

So my first guess was to try forcing the Mac to always negotiate 75Hz with the monitor. I tried using RDM to set the refresh rate, no dice. It always gets reset to the dynamic one when the monitor wakes.

Second guess was to mess with the monitor settings. Tried switching to DP 1.1 instead of 1.2, which made no difference. I can't use HDMI because that port is already used for another screen, but I doubt it makes a difference. Btw, the DP port is on a CalDigit TB dock.

How can I fix this?

Edit: [Found a question on Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253306846) about Monterey causing issues. I guess VRR is a new feature that's buggy. Solution is to disable adaptive sync on the monitor... but my monitor has no such setting.

Comment: Any reason you're not updating to Ventura?

Comment: @benwiggy I didn't know about it, haha. Normally my Mac bugs me about updates, but lately it hasn't. I'll give it a shot.